# Datepickerview issue transparent interaction

Tags: ios, ios7, uiscrollview, uidatepicker

I am displaying datepicker from bottom. And added as subview of scrollview. When Picker is on screen I can scroll my scrollview thorugh pickerview also. I dont want to scroll that scrollview at that time and I also dont want to disable scroll at the tiome of displaying date picker. I just dont want to interact scrollview thorugh pickerview. I am using ios7

Answer (score 0):

Don't add pickerview in scrollview.When you show pickerview set scrollview height deducting pickerview height and add pickerview in your view as subview instead of scrollview subview.

scrollview.frame = CGRectMake(scrollview.frame.origin.x,scrollview.frame.origin.y,scrollview.frame.size.width,scrollview.frame.size.height-pickerview.frame.size.height)